# Is the question whether a FO formula F has a model of size k (k is a finite number) decidable?

Tags: decidability

Hi all,

can someone please tell me whether the question whether a FO formula F has a model of size k (where k is a finite number) is decidable?

Thanks in advance!
TL

Comment: Sure. Just check all the possible interpretations for all the formula's function and relation symbols over the domain `$\{1,2,\dots,k\}$`.  

Comment: Note that in Andreas's answer (and the question, too), $k$ can be replaced by $k$ or fewer elements without changing the character of decidability.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.19